# Analytic bijection from $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ to itself

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is:

Let $f$ be an analytic bijection from $\mathbb{C} - \{0\} \to \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ such that $f(1)=1$ then either $f(z) = z$ or $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$.

My idea is use the Laurent expansion at $z = 0$, if the singularity is essential then by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem + open mapping theorem I was able to show that the function is not injective.

So $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^N c_{-k} z^{-k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k z^k$.

But here I am stuck, I guess the next step would be to show that all the $c_{-k}$ are zero except possibly at $c_{-1}$, but I don't know how to show that and we are not done anyway since there should be a way to show that all the coefficients $c_k$ are zero for $k > 1$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds fine so far. The next step is to repeat what you’ve done at $\infty$: if there is an essential singularity that also contradicts injectivity. So the Laurent series only has finitely-many terms. In other words $f$ is a ratio of the form $P(z)/z^k$, $P$ a polynomial. Since $f$ is a bijection on the complement of $\{0\}$, there can only be no $z\in\mathbb C\setminus0$ where $f(z)=0$, which can only happen where $P(z)=0$. The fundamental theorem of algebra implies then that $P(z)=z^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$ (otherwise it would have more roots). Similarly, there is only one $z\in\mathbb C\setminus0$ where $f(z)=1$; we know it’s $z=1$. Therefore if we solve $P(z)/z^k=z^{m-k}=1$, $z=1$ should be the only solution. You definitely know about roots of unity so this implies either $m-k=-1$ or $1$ (Clearly the $m-k=0$ case doesn’t work.)